# What type of flooring material is this and how do I fix it?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

I bought my house a year ago and I started seeing these cracks in my kitchen floor. I think this flooring type is called vinyl but looks like this kind of vinyl flooring is bit older. So 3 questions for the experts here:

1. Is this vinyl or something else?
2. How do I go about patching this up?

Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like sheet vinyl.  It goes down like carpet(rolled out).  Usually it is just covered over with new sheet vinyl or vinyl tiles or a different type of flooring.  Depending on the people, vinyl is almost a temporary flooring, It does not stand up well in most homes, but is usually one of the least expensive.

Comment: Thank you @crip659

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some sort of 'self levelling' compound was used to try to flatten the floor before laying the vinyl. This often isn't properly bonded to the concrete, (especially at the edges where it is the thinnest) and starts to fail after a few years. Hence the issue with the vinyl also breaking up.

Only solution if to lift up the vinyl, clean up any broken concrete/ self levelling compound and make repairs to the concrete before laying a new floor covering.